# Error when performing ANCOVA

Tags: r, robust

I am a beginner in R and maybe this questions is answer somewhere else. But I couldn't find an answer about it. 
I am trying to perform an `ANCOVA` using package `WRS2`, so I have written this formula:

`ancova(dep2~CCog+dep1 data=depres)`

but I always get the same error message:

`Error in ancova(dep2~CCog+dep1 data=depres) : object 'change' not found`

I don't know what is the problem, I have tried to perform the analysis with different data, but I have the same problem.

Comment: Could you share some of your data?  `dput()` of all the relevant objects will give people a dataset identical to yours to play with

Comment: At first, I though the data was the problem, but I have tried with different dataset and I get the same error message even I have performed ANCOVA with "mtcars" and I get the same error message. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: I tried the test with the data that is mentioned in the helpfile from `?ancova` (which is invisibility) and it worked. It could be that the call with the datasets needs to be of a particular form.